# push nav parameter to another page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, nav, ionic4, radio-group

l am using ionic4 and angular . l  have this page setting content radio group  .

[image]

how to do  when user click one of this choice he will  push value direct to home page . then use value he is selected use in home page to display information for data json .

page setting code

```
   export class PopoverstationsPage implements OnInit {
      cities :any
      constructor(public nav : NavController) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.cities)
      }

    }
```

html

```
    <ion-list>
            <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="cities">
                <ion-list-header>
                    <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
                </ion-list-header>

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>ميناء خصب</ion-label>
                    <ion-radio slot="start" value="26.2105,56.244" ></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>مطار خصب</ion-label>
                    <ion-radio slot="start" value="26.161722,56.23672"></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>دبا</ion-label>
                    <ion-radio slot="start" value="25.615627,56.247322"></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>البريمي</ion-label>
                    <ion-radio slot="start" value="24.233913,55.916176"></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>

            </ion-radio-group>
      </ion-list>
```

home page weather

```
    export class HomePage implements OnInit {
      cities :any
      constructor(public nav : NavController, private https: HttpClient) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.test ()
      }

async test (){

  this.https.get('weather/'+this.cities+'.json')
  .subscribe(data => {

    this.weather = data

  })


}

    }
```

Comment: Actually your question is not clear. do you need to open another page with the selected value of radio button ?

Comment: yes exactly , when user selected value of radio button he navigate to home page with value he is selected , because this value he is selected she is going to use in home page to display information for data json , l hope you understand my and sorry for weak language

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda you can check my update question

Comment: Ok I am looking your issue.

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda l found this [https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal] maybe help you

Comment: Check my answer